# Reindex data in an array such that missing data points are filled with NaNs

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, nan

I have several arrays like the one below:

```
[[ 0.          1.          0.73475787  0.36224658  0.08579446 -0.11767365
  -0.09927562  0.17444341  0.47212111  1.00584593  1.69147789  1.89421069
   1.4718292 ]
 [ 2.          1.          0.68744907  0.38420843  0.25922927  0.04719614
   0.00841919  0.21967246  0.22183329  0.28910002  0.54637077 -0.04389335
  -1.33445338]
 [ 3.          1.          0.77854922  0.41093192  0.0713814  -0.08194854
  -0.07885753  0.1491798   0.56297583  1.0759857   1.57149366  1.37958867
   0.64409152]
 [ 5.          1.          0.09182989  0.14988215 -0.1272845   0.12154707
  -0.01194815 -0.06136953  0.18783772  0.46631855  0.78850281  0.64755372
   0.69757144]]
```

Please note, that array[i,0] gives me a count. In this particular array counts 1, 4, and 6 are missing. In other case I might 2, 3, 5 or what not missing.

Now, for my later metaanalysis I would like to have the arrays  to have all NaNs included for missing counts.

In the above example, I would like to have

```
[[ 0.          1.          0.73475787  0.36224658  0.08579446 -0.11767365
  -0.09927562  0.17444341  0.47212111  1.00584593  1.69147789  1.89421069
   1.4718292 ]
[[ 1.          NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN
   NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN
   NaN ]
 [ 2.          1.          0.68744907  0.38420843  0.25922927  0.04719614
   0.00841919  0.21967246  0.22183329  0.28910002  0.54637077 -0.04389335
  -1.33445338]
 [ 3.          1.          0.77854922  0.41093192  0.0713814  -0.08194854
  -0.07885753  0.1491798   0.56297583  1.0759857   1.57149366  1.37958867
   0.64409152]
[[ 4.          NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN
   NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN
   NaN ]
 [ 5.          1.          0.09182989  0.14988215 -0.1272845   0.12154707
  -0.01194815 -0.06136953  0.18783772  0.46631855  0.78850281  0.64755372
   0.69757144]]
[[ 6.          NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN
   NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN
   NaN ]
```

To re-sort my arrays have tried the following:

```
influence_incl_missing = np.ones((len(vec_conc),len(results)+1))
for i, conc in enumerate(vec_conc):
    if i == influence[i,0]:
        influence_incl_missing[i,:] = influence[i,:]
    else:
        influence_incl_missing[i,1:] = np.full(len(results),np.nan)
        influence_incl_missing[i,0] = i
```

This gives me the obvious error

```
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

since len(influence) < len(vec_conc).

How can I do this in python?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Do you have pandas?

Comment: How such context "metaanalysis of a drug interference study" can help us to answer on "Sort data in python, such that missing data points are filled with NaNs" question?
Please, ask your question more abstract.

Comment: nope, don't have pandas. sounds like it might be worth it?

Comment: need sample input to answer. you really want to use `pandas`

Comment: this is unusable input data your question will get closed like this. what are we supposed to do with that data?

Comment: sorry, I suppose i got people confused with the metaanalysis story. Should have just asked how to include those NaNs for missing data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install pandas:

```
pip install pandas
```

---

Load your data into a `pandas` dataframe and apply a `reindex` operation – that should do it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)  # arr is your array

arr = df.set_index(df.columns[0])\
        .reindex(range(len(vec_conc)))\
        .reset_index().values
```

---

```
arr 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.73475787,  0.36224658,  0.08579446,
        -0.11767365, -0.09927562,  0.17444341,  0.47212111,  1.00584593,
         1.69147789,  1.89421069,  1.4718292 ],
       [ 1.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 2.        ,  1.        ,  0.68744907,  0.38420843,  0.25922927,
         0.04719614,  0.00841919,  0.21967246,  0.22183329,  0.28910002,
         0.54637077, -0.04389335, -1.33445338],
       [ 3.        ,  1.        ,  0.77854922,  0.41093192,  0.0713814 ,
        -0.08194854, -0.07885753,  0.1491798 ,  0.56297583,  1.0759857 ,
         1.57149366,  1.37958867,  0.64409152],
       [ 4.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 5.        ,  1.        ,  0.09182989,  0.14988215, -0.1272845 ,
         0.12154707, -0.01194815, -0.06136953,  0.18783772,  0.46631855,
         0.78850281,  0.64755372,  0.69757144],
       [ 6.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

Comment: sweet, pandas was actually installed within anaconda and did the job right away!